# Script que apaga arquivos pelas extensoes

Tags: windows, script, batch

Queria apagar diversos tipos de extensões, so que nao sei incrementar if em batch, alguem poderia me ajudar e me ensinar como incrementar o if no codigo abaixo:

```
@echo off
cd E:\comp_softwares
pause
Del /f /s /q *.mp3
pause
cls
echo Operacao Terminada.
pause>null
exit.
```

Comment: Tem que ser exatamente em Windows?  Em linux, isso seria bem fácil. Mas exibe alguma mensagem quando você executa?

Comment: por favor para windows, eu ja deixei a mensagem operacao terminada assim que ele apagar.

Comment: Douglas, eu nao entendo muito batch, mas se der uma ajuda, queria +/- isto

Comment: Postei a resposta abaixo. Caso resolva seu problema, marque a como Aceita por favor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe básica é essa:

```
if "%variavel%" == "XD" (
    Comandos a serem executados
) ELSE (
    Comandos a serem executados
)
```

Agora você precisa adaptar ao seu script.